# Video Encode different parts of video using different bitrates

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

If I've a video like: video-lectures

[image]

And I need to encode the slides with high bitrate (as it's the most important to the user) and encode the rest of the view with low bitrate.

1. Select the part to encode with high bitratre.
   [image]
2. Separately Encoding the different parts with different bitrates.

[image] [image]

3. Combine the different parts into one video.

The purpose is to reduce the total file-size to be published online, hence reduce the bandwidth needed.
I need to do that using ffmpeg.
I'll use that approach in encoding video-lectures recorded with still camera (180 degree view like the images above), since I know which regions are more useful to students (board and slides) than other regions.

Answer (score 5):

Videos can not be composited together without re transcoding. Hence your approach will not work. There is an option in libx264 to set per macroblock quantizer offset values. With this, you can tell the encoder to spend more or fewer bits encoding specific areas of the image. This option is not exposed via the command line however, so would need to write a custom tool using lib264 or modify the existing x264.

Comment: "Videos can not be composited together without re transcoding" make sense ... about "setting per macroblock quantizer offset values" can you provide me some references? .. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is the purpose for doing this just to reduce filesize or are you actually trying to effect the video for visual reasons?

Either way, it is possible to do this however it may not be the easiest way to achieve your goal.

Off the top of my head I would suggest simply breaking up your video into different segments and exporting at different rates. You could then bring them back together as one video. The resulting file would have one bitrate, but the individual sections would be of lower/higher quality.

If you can provide a little more information I may be able to assist further.

What software are you using?
Is this for stills or motion video?
Are you just trying to create an effect?

Comment: The purpose is to reduce the total file-size to be published online, hence reduce the bandwidth needed.
I need to do that using ffmpeg.
I'll use that approach in encoding video-lectures recorded with still camera (180 degree view like the images above), since I know which regions is more useful to students (board and slides) than other regions.

Answer (score 0):

A good codec (like H264) already does this: it will find details (static and over time) and distribute its available data so that what requires more detail (the bright screen) will be represented with more data, and what requires little (the rest which is dark, fuzzy and does not change much) will be represented with less data. In short, a good codec does almost exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You are right. However, if you noticed the images above, you will find some parts that's not important (like: lamps) and the encoder will represent them with more data as they have some details and bright.

Comment: No, it won't as those details are static (I assume the camera is on a tripod and not moving).

Comment: @MikeVersteeg When you give advice like this you should mention that H.264 is an open but not royalty free standard and there may be licensing fees  imposed by MPEG LA depending on the number of your users.